# To wholeheartedly commit to something and disregard everything but your focus

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What are English idioms or phrases that mean "to take your brain out and throw yourself at whatever obstacle/task/challenge etc. is in front of you", or similarly to stride forward relentlessly.

For example

> The small goblin ran ___________ to catch up with the larger, faster ogre.

> The pro longboarder gunned it _____________ down that mountain.

> When I am inspired to start a project, I rush through it ____________.

What is the actual phrase I am trying to find?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site does not exist to help you remember expressions.

Comment: @David other StackExchange sites seem to strive to build up a Q&A repository, to help future readers find the answers to the same questions. I think for example the end goal of StackOverflow is that no one should have to ask a question on it, because their question has already been asked and answered. If my searches for the phrases which are now in the body of the question, or my searches for the title of my question, had returned the phrase I was looking for, then I wouldn't have had to ask this question. But now my question might be helpful to people who struggle to find this phrase too.

Comment: @David would an open-ended question have been more on-topic in your opinion? "What are some phrases that mean 'to commit to something with determined recklessness, great speed, and lack of restraint'?" I can see that this is more similar to the normal [[single-word-requests]] questions that are asked.

Comment: In summary, yes. The open-ended question and an example sentence would fit the format. Stackoverflow works the same way; questions would generally apply to anyone else in the same situation. If you asked the name of an algorithm you couldn't remember with sound-alike examples, you'd likely be closed there too.

Comment: I think it is no longer off-topic by that measure then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go **hell-for-leather [/ hell for leather]** [after something]

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hell-for-leather) defines the adverb in terms of the adjective:

> **hell-for-leather** adjective  ... 2.2
>
> marked by determined recklessness, great speed, or lack of restraint
>
> *a cocky, hell-for-leather fighting man* — H. H. Martin

..................

> **hell-for-leather** [adv]
>
> in a hell-for-leather manner
>
> *rode hell-for-leather down the trail*

another example:

> Rather than building an early childhood system fit for purpose, based
>   on democratic deliberation of alternatives, New Labour went hell for
>   leather after expansion and opted for a strategy that was basically
>   more of the same.

['For a new public early childhood education'](https://reclaimingschools.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/for-a-new-public-early-childhood-education.pdf)
by Peter Moss, Emeritus Professor, UCL Institute of Education.